# Excel bottom up autofill/addition

Tags: excel, formula, backlog

I need to fill and add up the values in column with the value below, if the value is null or 0, I want it to use the previous field value.  This is part of my backlog calculation, and I can't find/remember the formula I used last time.

A is what I have, b is what I need

```
    A    B
   21    34
    6    13
    3    7
    1    4
    1    3
         2
    1    2
         1
         1
         1
         1
         1
    1    1
```

Comment: in B1: `=A1+B2` and then copy down???

Comment: that does not keep the previous value - if the cell is blank, it would put one, but on the copy up, the next two are both 0.  excel does not calculate with the calculated value.

Comment: or, if you do not want to drag down till the end: B1: `=SUM(A:A)` and B2: `=SUM(A:A)-SUM(A$1:A1)`... the B2-formula can be copied anywhere down and will show the correct value (even if the rest of B:B is empty...

Comment: if I have the numbers from A in column A, and put in B1 the first formula, and auto-fill it down till the last value, it shows the correct values...

Comment: gotcha - sorry, I had a brain fart with that.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),B2,A1+B2)
```